# How would one prove that $f(x) < (a^2-2a+x)/a^2$ if $f(x)=(x-1)/x$?

Tags: real-analysis

Really stuck with this: show that for $x>a>0$,
$$f(x)<\frac{a^2-2a+x}{a^2}.$$
I think i need to use the result of $f'(x)=1/x^2$ but i don't see how to apply it. Many thanks.

Comment: I think $x$ has to be positive, otherwise the inequality doesn't hold. Why do you want to prove it using MVT? Because you can solve it with simple algebra.

Comment: Please edit your question and say for which $x$ and $a$ such inequality should hold.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for a **geometric** approach: note that for $a\not=0$, $y=(a^2-2a+x)/a^2$ is a *special* line with respect to the graph of $f$ and $f$ is strictly concave for $x>0$.

Hint for an **algebraic** approach: verify that for $x>0$ with $x\not=a$ and $a\not=0$,
$$\frac{x-1}{x}<\frac{a^2-2a+x}{a^2}$$
that is
$$\frac{x(a^2-2a+x)-a^2(x-1)}{a^2x}>0.$$

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that
$$1-\frac{1}{x}<1+\frac{x-2a}{a^2}$$ or
$$\frac{(a-x)^2}{xa^2}>0.$$
We see that your inequality is true for any positive $x$ and for any non zero real value of $a$,

which   different than a value of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x}$ is differentiable and [strictly concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Properties) in the interval $x>0$, because:
$$f''(x)=(f'(x))'=(\frac1{x^2})'=-\frac2{x^3}<0.$$

The convex function satisfies the [condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function#Properties):
$$f(x)<f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)<\frac{a-1}{a}+\frac{1}{a^2}(x-a)=\frac{a^2-2a+x}{a^2}.$$
Graphical illustration:

$\hspace{2cm}$[image]
$$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}<f'(a) \iff f(x)<f(a)+f'(a)(x-a).$$